# uncomment all adjacent lines of comments without counting the lines

Tags: ideavim

```
//console.log('not this, since it is not adjancent')
console.log()
// console.log("uncomment this")
// console.log("uncomment this")  <-- cursor may be at this at this line for instance
// console.log("uncomment this")
// console.log("uncomment this")
// console.log("uncomment this")
console.log()
//console.log('not this, since it is not adjancent')
```

Is it possible to type some command to uncomment all these adjacent lines of comments without having to count the lines.

I know I can do `gc5j`, but I don't want to count lines.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the [commentary plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)?

Comment: `gc5j` also works with the [tcomment plugin](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), though `gcgc` and `gcu` don’t. tcomment does not seem to have such a feature.

Comment: Thanks for your input , but I don't think the plugins you mentioned works with `ideavim`

Comment: Actually, I think the vim-commentary and tcomment plugins are supported in ideavim, see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/Emulated-plugins), under the "commentary" heading.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using tpope's [commentary plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary), see `:help gcgc` or `:help gcu`:

```
gcgc     Uncomment the current and adjacent commented lines.
gcu
```

As pointed out by @D. Ben. Knoble, `gc` is both an operator *and* a text object! So `gc<some motion>` will toggle the comment of  but `dgc` will `d`elete the commented block under the cursor and `>gc` will indent the commented block etc.

Comment: I don't think that specific plugin works with `ideavim`?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen I guess not, I haven't used ideavim so I can't be sure

Comment: @SebastianNielsen It seems to me that commentary plugin is supported (or at least emulated) in ideavim, see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/Emulated-plugins)

Comment: tpope's plugin also provides `gc` as a text object, so `dgc` and similar become possible

Comment: Yes it's a very nice feature: I use `>gc` quite often to further indent a comment block

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is by creating a folding rule for the comments in the syntax file. Then you can operate on all the folded lines. Another useful technique is to select the lines in visual mode then apply your operation.

Comment: Is it possible to create a macro for all that, so that you can accomplish it in one short command, e.g. `gcu`?

Comment: Operating on things in visual mode is a generally useful technique, and could also be used for commenting out code. If you want a simple shortcut you should use the other answer probably. If I were to write a macro, I'd search backwards and forwards for the comment pattern and substitute on the lines you found.